# How to monkey path python special method without defining them first?

Tags: python

Why does the following

```
class A(object): pass
class B: pass

def p(x): print x

a = A()
b = B()

a.__enter__ = lambda *a, **k: p('a.enter')
b.__enter__ = lambda *a, **k: p('b.enter')
a.__exit__  = lambda *a, **k: p('a.exit')
b.__exit__  = lambda *a, **k: p('b.exit')

print 'direct call'
a.__enter__()
b.__enter__()
a.__exit__()
b.__exit__()

print 'with statement'
with a: pass
with b: pass
```

Print the following, but also throw an exception?

```
direct call
a.enter
b.enter
a.exit
b.exit
with statement
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lol.py", line 21, in <module>
    with a: pass
AttributeError: __exit__
```

GamesBrainiac is correct that I'm looking to monkey-patch an instance.  The reason for this is that the standard way to use the `logging` standard library is a combination of `getLoggerClass`/`setLoggerClass` and `getLogger`.  Using the former pair will override all future behavior (undesireable) and using the latter appears to preclude me from monkey-patching the object to have special behavior.

Comment: If you can wait a little bit, I'm writing you a fleshed out answer.

Comment: I think I've provided you with a solution, am I mistaken?

Comment: @AaronHall I tried man. But, I guess you _cant_ do it. Because its not defined with `__dict__`.

Comment: @AaronHall Waaaaiiittt! I think I monkey patched the special method!

Comment: @AaronHall Done! Man, it feels good to be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently context manager functions only work with classes. You're defining them on the instance. From the python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#context-manager-types):

> Python’s with statement supports the concept of a runtime context defined by a context manager. This is implemented using a pair of methods that allow user-defined **classes** to define a runtime context that is entered before the statement body is executed and exited when the statement ends:

However, I did come up with this hack which I think will work for you:

```
class A:
    pass

def p(x):
    print(x)

a = A()

class MonkeyPatched(a.__class__):
    pass

MonkeyPatched.__enter__ = lambda *a, **k: p('a.enter')
MonkeyPatched.__exit__  = lambda *a, **k: p('a.exit')

a.__class__ = MonkeyPatched

with a:
    pass

a = A()

with a:
    pass
```

The first `with` works, but not the second.

This is rather ugly and I'm not sure if there are side effects of setting `__class__`.

Comment: *All* member functions are looked up via the class. You can get around that limitation by actually modifying the class.

Comment: @filmor But I think op wants to monkey patch the instance.

Comment: I don't think Zach wants to modify the class.

Comment: This is python, have a look at my answer on what I meant. Sorry for the lack of expressiveness, posting from mobile.

Comment: Giving you the points since you had the documentation on *why* it didn't work, and including an example for the specific use.

@Filmor, that does not appear to be accurate.  Normal lookups don't work this way: https://gist.github.com/zachriggle/2b21203d263a6d8da617

Comment: @ZachRiggle *Member functions* are always looked up like this. By member function I mean a function that gets its first attribute implicitly assigned to the object it is called on ("`self`"). Sure, you can place a function in a normal instance attribute, but that is not the same (as you have seen). Additionally, the special member functions (i.e. `__call__`, `__add__` and the like) are always resolved as member functions in the given sense.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Response**

You lambdas are unbound methods. When a is passed, it uses the `__exit__` method of the class, not the instance. Since the class has no method, it's an attribute error.

To demonstrate:

```
class C(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        print 'entered'
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        print self
        print exc_type
        print 'exiting'

c = C()
with c:
    print 'inside context'
```

prints:

```
entered
inside context
<__main__.C object at 0x7fd885e4eed0>
None
exiting
```

but when we assign an lambda, we still get the bound method:

```
c.__exit__ = lambda *args: p('lambda exit')
with c:
    print 'inside context'
```

prints:

```
entered
inside context
<__main__.C object at 0x7fd885e4eed0>
None
exiting
```

You can mock the class method with the mock library (I had to get it from the Ubuntu repos for python 2 with `sudo apt-get install python-mock), unittest.mock in Python 3's standard lib:

```
import mock # unittest.mock in Python 3
with mock.patch.object(C, '__exit__', autospec=True) as mock_method:
    new_c = C()
    with new_c:
        print 'inside context'

# __exit__ is called with three None's if no exception
mock_method.assert_called_with(new_c, None, None, None)
```

prints:

```
entered
inside context
```

Note that the original `__exit__` method is no longer called.

Comment: That was a typo.  Changing that to `lambda: p('...')` still throws the exception.  Problem updated.

Comment: Yes, you can do this, but he wanted monkey patched bound context managers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to "monkey-patch" the class of the respective instance:

```
new_class = type(a.__class__.__name__, (a.__class__,), {})
new_class.__enter__ = ...
new_class.__exit__ = ...
a.__class__ = new_class
```

Comment: But in essence you are still creating a new class.

Comment: He *is* creating a new class. This doesn't answer.

Comment: This does appear to be the proper way to do it without modifying the original class.  This solution is the same as simonzack's, but I can only give points to one of you.  I've adopted an approach similar to both of your answers.

Comment: I am creating a class that behaves exactly like the class before, it has even the same name (note that this is a (minor) difference to simonzack's solution). In particular, things like `isinstance` and `issubclass` will continue to work as expected as long as you don't use `a.__class__` for this. IMHO this is the only pythonic way to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, since `__enter__` is bound to `__class__`:

```
from types import MethodType


class A(object):
    pass




class B(object):
    pass

a = A()
b = B()


def p(x):
    print(x)


def en(self, *args):
    p('starting')
    return self


def ex(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
    p('finishing')
    return False

a.__class__.__enter__ = MethodType(en, a)
a.__class__.__exit__ = MethodType(ex, a)

with a:
    print("Inside stuff")
```

Comment: Apart from being nearly the same as simonzack's and my answer, this modifies `A` directly. After this *all* instances of `A` will have the overwritten `__enter__` and `__exit__` functions, which, btw. will always have `a` as their `self` attribute!

Comment: I edited it once (the `type` call was messed up). That doesn't relate, however, to the problems in your solution :)